# Autohotkey - How to get windows' "head" position

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get the position of a window, so I can write a script to double click to that window. Is there any ways to do this in AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 2):

The question has [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey) tag, so I assume it's about [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), right?
If yes, all you need is [WinGetPos](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm) command, allowing you to get `x,y` coordinates of the upper left corner of the window.

```
WinGetPos [, X, Y, Width, Height, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
```

First four parameters are the names of variables, that will get info about the window.
Last four parameters are standard for almost all AutoHotkey Win-commands, they identify the window.

Simple example:

```php
SetTitleMatchMode 2             ;# match window title in any place
IfWinExist, Notepad
    WinGetPos, Xpos, Ypos       ;# Uses the window found above.
```

This will put the Notepad window position into `Xpos`, `Ypos` variables.
Then you can use those `Xpos`, `Ypos` variables with [Click](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) command to send the click.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off getting a handle to the window and using `SendMessage()` (or whatever the equivalent is on whatever platform you're on) to send a double-click message.